# Patent before beta release in India

Tags: filing, mobile, india

Is it necessary to patent an idea or innovation before a beta version is released in India?

Comment: It depends what potential patent rights you may be interested in securing.  More detail in the question is needed before a proper answer can be given.

Comment: I was talking about patents in software or ideas based on software applications.

Comment: @Vin Software is not patentable in India.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If you feel that it need a protection of IP then first you should file a patent application in India as well as  wipo this will ensure priority and if it satisfy all patent criteria you won't face any problem.

Comment: Thank for the help. Is it possible to file a patent after the release of the beta version? And if so, what is the duration from the date of the release that I can apply for the patent?

Comment: You have grace period for India,  for rest of world you missed novelty